# iPhone4 supports Bluetooth HealthDeviceProfile HDP?

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth

Google provided few links and leads to confusion again and again. So, i am summarizing the questions. Kindly bare if questions repeated, and please provide the link for reference also.

1)  Does iPhone4/higherversion/lowerversion/ support HDP on Bluetooth?

1a)  If supports, where can i see example code ?

1b)  Can i use objective-C to interact with HDP device?.

2) i noticed that iphone4 supports to Bluetooth Low Energy device which does not require MFI compliance ? is it so ?

3) I have certain libraries written in ANSI C++. Can the same be ported to ios?, Or 
   do i have to still consider Objective-C?

4) Can u provide few reliable links to move forward in this topic ?

Comment: Could someone have any input on it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any restriction on the types of profiles the iPhone supports.

Here's a good link for working with bluetooth: http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfilesHome.aspx

- that is a list of all bluetooth profiles, and you can also see all of their services and characteristics if you click into them.

This website also has some good explannations on BLE and some sample code:  http://ble.stalliance.no/

This is also some good sample code: https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/CoreBluetooth-Demo

Answer (score 1):

HDP is a Bluetooth BR/EDR (base rate) profile, and uses IEEE 11073 as their application protocol.

HDP profile is not adaptable to BTLE (low energy) devices, and low-energy devices do not use 11073; each device profile has its own set of characteristics.

The good thing in low-energy is that every profile uses the same building blocks (characteristics) and there is a single application protocol (GATT). Moreover, the characteristics layout is public in developer.bluetooth.org site.

As far as I know, BR/EDR development is very restricted on iOS, you can only use the profiles supplied by Apple (audio, that Nike sports device and... anything else?). In the other hand, there is an API for GATT/low energy, so in theory any kind of low-energy device can be used with iPhone.